# Why pastebinit is not available via pip?

Tags: pip, pypi, pastebin

I got this error messsage.

```
$ pip install pastebinit
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pastebinit (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pastebinit
```

But according to the following URL. It should be available. Does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks.

https://libraries.io/pypi/pastebinit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such project available on PyPI currently: https://pypi.org/project/pastebinit/

`libraries.io` is not an authoritative source. It also shows no currently available release for this project anyway: https://libraries.io/pypi/pastebinit/versions

The forge for this software seems to be here: https://launchpad.net/pastebinit

Answer (score 1):

Nop, it's not there. The URL https://pypi.org/project/pastebinit/ returns error 404. Perhaps it was there but later was removed.